# Cmake is finding GSL but I can't include gsl in my C++ script

Tags: c++, cmake, include

Why does Cmake find the library but I can't include it?

I am trying to use the gsl library in C++ but I get `gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h: No such file or directory` when I run `cmake --build` even though it says `-- Found GSL: /usr/include (found version "2.7.1")` in the terminal after running `cmake ..`.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04
I installed gsl with `sudo apt-get install libgsl-dev` and it is in `/usr/include`.

I think it might be a problem with the compiler I am using but I'm not sure how to check.

My CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(mujoco_gym)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
# It prevents the decay to C++98 when the compiler does not support C++14
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
# It disables the use of compiler-specific extensions
# e.g. -std=c++14 rather than -std=gnu++14
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")

find_package(GSL REQUIRED)
link_libraries(GSL::gsl)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES mujoco_gym.cpp)

add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries (
        ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
        ${GSL_LIBRARIES}
)
```

My .cpp file.

```
#include<stdbool.h> //for bool
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>

int main()
{
    double x = 5.0;
    std::cout << gsl_sf_bessel_j0(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Cmake and build in the terminal

```
$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/iii/miniconda3/envs/tf/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/iii/miniconda3/envs/tf/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.2") 
-- Found GSL: /usr/include (found version "2.7.1") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/iii/.mujoco/mujoco210/sample/build




$ cmake --build . --config Release
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mujoco_gym.dir/mujoco_gym.cpp.o
/home/iii/.mujoco/mujoco210/sample/mujoco_gym.cpp:21:10: fatal error: gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h: No such file or directory
   21 | #include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/mujoco_gym.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/mujoco_gym.dir/mujoco_gym.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/mujoco_gym.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
$
```

Comment: Sorry, everything looks right. What does `ls -l /usr/include/gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h` show?

Comment: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14165 Dec  6  2021 /usr/include/gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h`

Comment: You could start debugging by running `make VERBOSE=1` and checking, whether the command line for compilation contains required include directory.

Comment: I deactivate the virtual conda env I was in and it works without a hitch. I was trying different installs of gsl in that env so it must have been looking for some other gsl library in another place. I didn't consider this but it's obvious in hindsight. I wonder how to get the right `gsl` path in my env.

Comment: Instead of adding `link_libraries(GSL::gsl)` and `target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${GSL_LIBRARIES})` you should link to the imported target `GSL::gsl`, e.g. `target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE GSL::gsl)`. The imported target will add the necessary include dir.

Comment: @vre I put it in and I get `Target "mujoco_gym" links to target "GSL::gsl" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?
`